# programming language to build an online chatting service

Tags: web-applications, chat

what is the best suited programming language and technologies to make an online chatting service that scales up to support 50.000 users at the same time such us the band width usage stays at minimum (web server friendly). I have considered using php or python, are they good choices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the web-friendly languages (Perl, PHP, Python, Java/JSP) are OK on a back-end.
Your skills as a developer matter a lot more than choice of a language.

If you're Good Enough, use Lisp :) [ Frequent readers of JoelOnSoftware should catch the reference : ]

Comment: It's a functional language that gives you great leverage. Plus, Yahoo Shops was built with it :)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, [Facebook used Erlang to scale their chat to use 70 million users](http://highscalability.com/new-facebook-chat-feature-scales-70-million-users-using-erlang).  But Erlang is not at all like PHP or Python, and if you haven't had any exposure to a functional language before, there's certainly a bit of a learning curve.